# Pageup and Pagedown Command in iMacros

Tags: imacros

How do you use the Page-up and Page-down command in iMacros?

By Page-up, I mean the action that happens when you press the Page-Up or Pg-up Button. There are command for going home and end of the page. But, is there any page-up or page-down command in iMacros?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this workaround will be helpful to you:

```
' Page Up '
URL GOTO=javascript:window.scrollBy(0,-0.88*window.innerHeight);

' Page Down '
URL GOTO=javascript:window.scrollBy(0,0.88*window.innerHeight);
```

---

Here is a solution that works in ‘iMacros’ for Firefox:

```
' Page Up '
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR=* KEY=33

' Page Down '
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR=* KEY=34
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the code, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Tested both Chrome and Firefox.

Message: SyntaxError: unknown command: EVENT at line 5

Comment: Take a look at the [`EVENT` command](http://wiki.imacros.net/EVENT) and update of my answer.